# Splitting a single integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

After performing a dot product inside the integral this result was obtained. $P_1$ and $P_2$ are points in 3D space.

$$\int_{P_1}^{P_2} \textbf{A} \cdot \textbf{dl} = \int_{P_1}^{P_2} (xy \ dx + (3x-y^2) dy) = \int_{P_1}^{P_2} xy \ dx + \int_{P_1}^{P_2} 3x-y^2 \ dy  $$

***What rule was used to split this integral into two integrals in the last step?*** What confuses me is that there are two variables that produce two differential elements ***dx*** and ***dy*** that I dont know how to deal with during this split of the integral. In normal case I would use this:

$$ \int_a^bf(x)+g(x)dx = \int_a^bf(x) \ dx + \int_a^bg(x) \ dx  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to write $\int_a^b$ for a [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) (of a vector field) unless you are considering specifically the points $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$ on the $x$-axis and the line segment between them. In this case, you simply have $\int_a^b (3x-y^2)\,dy=0$.

Another possible interpretation is that you consider specific parameterization $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ and interpret your line integral as
$$
\int_\gamma p(x,y)dx+q(x,y)dy=\int_a^b p(\gamma(t)),q(\gamma(t)))\cdot \gamma'(t)\,dt
$$

---

Okay, according to your edit, you mean the first case. Now you simply have
$$
\int_P^Q F(r)\cdot dr=\int_P^Q F_1(x,y,z)dx+F_2(x,y,z)dy+F_3(x,y,z)dz. 
$$
where $F=(F_1,F_2,F_3)$.

In your example you have
$$
F_1(x,y,z)=xy,\quad
F_2(x,y,z)=3x-y^2,\quad
F_3(x,y,z)=0
$$

Now note that
$$
F=F_1e_1+F_2e_2+F_3e_3 
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\int_P^Q F\cdot dr
&= \int_P^Q (F_1e_1+F_2e_2+F_3e_3 )\cdot dr\\
&=\int_P^Q F_1 e_1\cdot dr+
\int_P^Q F_2 e_2\cdot dr+
\int_P^Q F_3 e_3\cdot dr\\
&=\int_P^Q F_1(x,y,z) dx+
\int_P^Q F_2(x,y,z) dy+
\int_P^Q F_3(x,y,z) dz
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for answer and sorry, you are right, I actually meant from a point a to point b n 3D space. I will clarify that in my question in an edit shortly.

Comment: @Clone:3D would be similar. Actually, you don't have $dz$ in your integral and you only have a 2D vector field.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, It clarified a lot!

Comment: @Clone: you are welcome!